# Eliminate Null Query results from a user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the following user defined function that runs correctly; however, it shows all records that return 0 when checked against the ISDATE condition.  These records are displayed as NULL values in the query results.  I don't want to see those records.  How can I remove them from the query results?

I had to setup the ISDATE() check because some log entries have the following format:

(**"Due Date: -> xx/xx/xxxx"** instead of **"Due Date: xx/xx/xxxx -> yy/yy/yyyy"**)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION ParseValueFromChgLog 
(
    @LogText varchar(max), 
    @ValueNum int -- 1 = original date or 2 = changed to date
)
RETURNS date    
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result date
    DECLARE @ValueCheck char(1)
    DECLARE @Index bigint
    DECLARE @OrigStep bigint
    DECLARE @StrDate varchar(max)   

        -- Parse "Original Date"
        IF @ValueNum = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @Index = 10
            SET @OrigStep = 8
            SET @StrDate = SUBSTRING(@LogText,CHARINDEX('Due Date', @LogText)+ @Index, @OrigStep)                   
            IF ISDATE(@StrDate) = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LogText,CHARINDEX('Due Date', @LogText)+ @Index, @OrigStep)AS DATE)
                --SET @Result = @Date 
            END
        END

        -- Parse "Changed to Date" 
        IF @ValueNum = 2
        BEGIN
            SET @Index = 21
            SET @OrigStep = 9
            SET @StrDate = SUBSTRING(@LogText,CHARINDEX('Due Date', @LogText)+ @Index, @OrigStep)
            IF ISDATE(@StrDate) = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LogText,CHARINDEX('Due Date', @LogText)+ @Index, @OrigStep)AS DATE)
                --SET @Result = @Date
            END
        END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result 

END
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: OK I figured it out.  In the view WHERE clause I was trying to use the  alias name of the returned function ie. "WHERE alias IS NOT NULL" instead of using "user-defined-function IS NOT NULL".  Is there a better way to do this so I don't have to run the function twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way out of returning a value by this function.
But you can filter your query by `Where function_Column is not null`